# How to create fade animations?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android, and was trying to do a fade animation for an ImageView, when I came across a small problem

```
 ImageView batman = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.batmanb);
 batman.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(500);
```

I created an onClick for the ImageView with the ID `batman`, and wrote the code. However, instead of disappearing slowly over the 500ms, its disappears in it's entirety a few seconds later. Any suggestions as to what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **`Object Animator`** or **`AlphaAnimation`**

use,

```
ImageView batman= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(batman, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
objectAnimator.setDuration(500L);
objectAnimator.start();
```

or use,

```
AlphaAnimation fade_in = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
fade_in.setDuration(500);
yourImageView.startAnimation(fade_in);
```

Comment: What is the significance of the L in .setDuration(500L) ?

Comment: Just it represents "Long" type

Comment: In your code, You have used `ImageView batman = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.batmanb); ` . That's why I used batman. it is a view need to be animated (your imageview)

Comment: My imageView is still batman. I tried changing the ID and also adding another imageview, but unfortunately, ObjectAnimator is not recognizing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post the code what you have tried and check my edited answer

Comment: I used Build > Clean Project and it worked! Thank you so much for the answer, though the fade in is not smooth,but I'll try and work on that.

Comment: You can try the second one

Answer (score 0):

Create two xml files

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
  android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
  android:duration="500" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
  android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
  android:fillAfter="true"
  android:duration="500" />
```

On Click event for fade_in animation use this code

```
   Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FadeInFadOutAnimationActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
   YOUR_IMAGE.startAnimation(animation);
   YOUR_IMAGE.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

On Click event for fade_out animation use this code

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FadeInFadOutAnimationActivity.this, R.anim.fade_out);
YOUR_IMAGE.startAnimation(animation);
YOUR_IMAGE.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```